# Why doesn’t lightning punch a hole in the fuselage?

Tags: safety, wing, electrical-system, fuselage

Electric arcing creates a huge temperature in the air around it. When lightning strikes planes, why doesn’t this high temperature air melt/deform the aircraft skin? Also can these high temperatures ignite fuel in the wings?

Comment: What is arcing?  I mean, what is arcing **between**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Potentially, yes, but this would be a very rare event. The principal reason that lightning does not create damage to an aircraft is that the airframe, particularly aluminum airframes, are electrically conductive, and carry the charge easily around them with very little resistance, which would otherwise create heat. Essentially, the airframe behaves like a Faraday cage and protects the contents within from damage. The airframe is also designed to dissipate static electric charges through static wicks, lightning runners and lightning spikes on the exterior of the skin.  Fiberglass parts such as radomes are protected by lightning runners which carry the charge and protect electronic components underneath.  Composite aircraft made from e-glass are constructed with a stainless steel mesh ply imbedded in the skin which channels and carries electric charges.

Lightning strike protection is a critical part of aircraft certification under parts 23, 25, 27 and 29.  Very rarely has lightning caused any kind of an accident, and commercial aircraft are frequently struck by lightning every year and suffer almost no ill effects from it.

Comment: The question is about "high temperature air" so I do not see how the conductivity of the airframe answers that part of the question.

Comment: Those kinds of air temperatures last in the timeframe of milliseconds. Not exactly enough time to heat up and melt and/or deform the skin in.

Comment: Just because the temperature is high, doesn't mean that it is magic and blows up like a bomb. The spark from a grinder is **melted metal**, but the total heat energy is so low that the workers usually don't need any extra protection around it, even if it is sprayed all over their body.

Comment: Re Nelson's comment on grinder sparks, I can show him my glove where the spray burned a channel through the back within minutes.

Comment: "Composite aircraft made from e-glass are constructed with a stainless steel mesh ply imbedded in the skin which channels and carries electric charges." I've wondered about re-certification as they age, embedded metal mesh with 20 years of occasional desert heat sounds like a recipe for gaps in protection.

Comment: @AndyDent sure, but that it took minutes to burn that channel is supporting evidence for the claim that microsecond exposures aren't going to matter.

Comment: @AndyDent I'm sure if you dipped the glove in molten steel it'll combust much faster.

Comment: Side note: _commercial aircraft are frequently struck by lightning every year and suffer almost no ill effects from it._ Granted, but what about the passengers? See: [Frequent Flyers Could Take a Hit of Radiation from Lightning](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/frequent-flyers-could-take-a-hit-of-radiation-from-lightning/) and ['Dark lightning': The mysterious radiation that might be zapping air passengers mid-flight](https://www.euronews.com/next/2023/01/12/dark-lightning-the-mysterious-radiation-that-might-be-zapping-flight-passengers-mid-air) An issue [or not]?

Comment: @CraigEstey Refer to the [Radiation Dosage chart](https://xkcd.com/radiation/) by XKCD.

Comment: Though there must have been some lessons learned in the early days of aviation...

Comment: Don't forget that the aircraft is moving through the air at speed. The piece of air that was superheated is far behind the aircraft very quickly!

Answer (score 18):

The other answers mention aircraft have a high electrical conductivity.  However, air has a much lower electrical conductivity and does get hot, as you mentioned.

The hot air causes little damage because:

- The electrical current only heats a small area of the air for a brief period.
- The air expands quickly, causing it to cool quickly.
- The aircraft moves quickly, so it is only exposed to the heat briefly.  After that, it is exposed to very cold air that can remove the heat.
- Since the aircraft skin is electrically conductive, it also conducts heat away from the hot area.

Comment: Also the metal has much higher heat capacity, so the same amount of energy heats it less then it heats the air, and good thermal conductivity, so the heat spreads quickly further reducing the thermal stress on the point of contact.

Comment: Bullet 1: Actually, part of the point is that a lightning strike is much LESS concentrated, and much shorter than pretty much any other arc, whether that be an accidental wiring issue, or from some sort of welding.
Bullet 4: Electrical conductivity and temperature conductivity are not the same thing.

Comment: @MikeB while not being the same thing, good electric conductors are usually also good thermal conductors (see an answer at [physlink.com](https://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae432.cfm), or the sortable list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities)) it's not working the other way.

Answer (score 17):

Why doesn't it punch holes in the fuselage? [It can](https://viewfromthewing.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/american-787-lightning-strike.jpg).

Can it ignite fuel in wings? Yes, lightning creates sparks that can potentially ignite fuel vapors. The liquid fuel itself does not ignite, but the vapors can.

Both of these things are extraordinarily rare, however. Planes are specially designed to be resistant to lighting strikes, and most lightning strikes result in little to no damage.

Comment: All true. But please speak to how rare this is. I have to fly with people who read this.

Comment: Each airplane is struck, on average, 1-2 times per year:  https://www.weather.gov/safety/lightning-planes   https://flightsafety.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/asw_jun10_p18-23.pdf

Comment: It should be noted that damage like shown in the linked picture is, at the moment it happens, completely inconsequential. The structural elements around it are strong enough to prevent the hole from growing bigger and the outflow valves are bigger than that so they'll just close a bit and the pressurization can keep up just fine. Only long term the damage would spread mostly due to metal fatigue, so it has to be repaired after landing. But it wouldn't cause any immediate danger.

Comment: @JanHudec That hole looks big enough to put my hand in.  I'm not understanding how pressurization wouldn't cause a lot of extra work as now air will be blasting out of that hole which will need to be pumped back in...

Comment: @Michael The cabin is not sealed to keep air inside, but the engines or compressors are continuously pushing quite a large volume of air into the cabin while it leaks through all the imperfect seals and the outflow valves. Quick search says the outflow valves on a 777 have (the two of them together) area about 90 in²/580 cm². You can definitely put your hand through that.

Comment: @JanHudec Ah that makes sense, thanks.  Incidentally, if this "engines or compressors pushing a large volume of air into the cabin" the reason why at times the air has a bit of a distinct - I was to say almost oily - smell to it?

Comment: @Michael The hole depicted is in the skin of the wing, not through the pressure hull. The insides of the wing are not pressurized.

Comment: @Michael, Yes, most jet aircraft use ‘bleed air’ taken from the engine's compressor stage for pressurization and with that a bit of engine oil can get in. It's part of the reason why Boeing returned to using separate compressor in 787.

Comment: @Chris you sure that's a wing? It looks far too rounded to be a wing to me. But, I've been wrong before...

Comment: @FreeMan It looked like a wing to me, but now that you mention it, that looks like the tail in the background, which would make it the fuselage after all.

Comment: @Chris I thought that was the tail in the background, too, but it looks too long and has too many fairings along the bottom for me to want to claim that it's the horizontal stab. Again, though, I could be wrong. ;)

Answer (score 9):

When electric current flows through a medium, the amount of power dissipated is inversely proportional to the resistance of the medium. This is why the heating element in a space heater heats up, but the power cord leading to it doesn't (much): the element has a much higher resistance than the cord. This is also why using too small of an extension cord for the load can cause a fire: thinner conductors have a higher internal resistance.

Air has a much, much higher resistance than the aluminum, composites, etc. that they use to build planes, and hence gets much hotter during a lightning strike. This is easily seen in [videos of planes being hit by lightning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY56uIuCu-8), where the air glows from the heat and the plane doesn't. Furthermore, heat can't transfer from the air to the plane because it's almost immediately blown away by the slipstream.

Of course, that's not to say that it's impossible for lightning to cause damage, because it absolutely can. If the current finds a spot of higher-than-average resistance, or gets concentrated to a point, it can (and has) caused significant damage.

Comment: Wait, composite materials like carbon fiber have low electrical resistance?  Apparently that's true: https://carbonfibergear.com/blogs/carbonfiber/is-carbon-fiber-conductive#ol4   - neat.  Unlike fiberglass, which being made of glass is an insulator (one which doesn't ionize nearly as easily as air).

Comment: Fun fact: the amount of current that the power cord of a space heater carries is equivalent to about one typical lightning bolt every second. Passing that amount of current through air produces tremendous amounts of light, heat, and sound; passing that amount of current through a copper wire does practically nothing.

Comment: @TannerSwett I don't know where you picked up that little factoid, but it's not exactly accurate. A typical lightning bolt is well over 30,000 amps, while a typical household electrical socket is limited to 15 amps.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield Yes, now that I think about it, my comment is really not accurate at all. What is true is that the amount of charge carried by the power cord in a minute (about 700 coulombs) is a reasonable amount of charge for, say, 40 lightning bolts. When I wrote that comment, I was thinking that the actual instantaneous current doesn't matter—in other words, I was thinking that 30,000 amps for half a millisecond would be practically the same as 15 amps for one second—but now that I think about it some more, that's not true at all. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Wire heating from intermittent loads will be roughly proportional to duty cycle, but the square of the current, so reducing the duty cycle by a factor of 100 would only allow a 10-fond increase in current (rather than 100-fold) to keep the same level of heating.

Comment: @TannerSwett you're right but you're confusing people. The reason the power cord would do "practically nothing" like you say is because the lightning has to do much less work to travel over the copper than over the highly resistant air. It's why lightning rods work. Which is what you're building with this thought experiment. Extension cords don't typically get bigger than 10 gauge (AWG). Lightning rod wire must be 6 gauge (bigger). Typical extension cord has 3 wires. 3 10 gauge wires gives 5 gauge. So yeah, if you get lucky and the lightning hits all three wires evenly, "practically nothing".

Comment: "*Air has a much, much higher resistance than the aluminum*", lightning in air doesn't flow in air as a gaz, but in [air plasma](https://scied.ucar.edu/learning-zone/sun-space-weather/plasma) which is a very conductive.

Comment: @mins Plasma isn't "very conductive". Sure, it's a lot more conductive than non-ionized air, but it's still much *less* conductive than aluminum. Also, the current is what creates the plasma in the first place, so there must be at least *some* current flow before the plasma can exist.

Comment: Air ~$10^{-12}$ S/m,  carbon fiber ~$10^{-2}$, lightning plasma ~$10^{4}$, Al ~$10^{7}$. There is not much current before plasma appears, insulating molecules are broken by voltage, and turn into plasma quickly as current starts increasing and becomes a precursor.

Comment: @mins So, aluminum is about one thousand times more conductive than lightning plasma? Sure, sounds about right. Also, conductivity is only one factor in determining resistance. Resistance is also inversely proportional to the area of the conductor. A lightning bolt is only about an inch (2-3 cm) across. Planes are bigger than that, so the actual resistance is much lower.

Comment: Yes aluminum is more conductive than plasma, but the point is plasma is one million times more conductive than carbon fiber composites used in modern planes. In addition carbon fiber materials have a low thermal conductivity slowing down heat dispersion. Currents observed during lightning strikes on actual aircraft were up to 24kA, but for very short times. I think the reason is the short time rather than the large section of the conductor. Two studies: [1](https://aerospacelab.onera.fr/sites/w3.onera.fr.aerospacelab/files/AL05-06_2.pdf), [2](https://www.lsc.phy.cam.ac.uk/research/lightning).